# Cómo puedo ordenar una columna de fechas en el orden del calendario? Usando Pandas & Numpy

Tags: numpy, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo una columna que cargo desde un CSV, sin embargo se cargan con el orden que trae el CSV y no en orden calendario (mi fuente de datos tampoco ordena las fechas en orden de calendario).

```
    Fecha               Pais  count
0  2017-06-01          Argentina      1
1  2017-06-01              China  31230
2  2017-06-01            Ecuador      1
3  2017-06-01              Egypt      2
4  2017-06-01             Latvia    360
5  2017-06-01           Portugal      1
6  2017-06-01    Slovak Republic      2
7  2017-06-01             Taiwan      2
8  2017-06-01            Ukraine     31
9  2017-06-01     United Kingdom      1
10 2017-06-02          Argentina      2
11 2017-06-02             Canada      1
12 2017-06-02              China   3980
13 2017-06-02    Slovak Republic      3
14 2017-06-02             Sweden      1
15 2017-06-02            Ukraine     99
16 2017-05-30          Argentina      1
17 2017-05-30              China   4022
18 2017-05-30            Ecuador      1
19 2017-05-30             France     16
20 2017-05-30            Germany      2
21 2017-05-30          Indonesia      1
22 2017-05-30    No Identificado     56
23 2017-05-30            Romania      1
24 2017-05-30             Russia      4
25 2017-05-30             Sweden    158
26 2017-05-30             Taiwan      1
27 2017-05-30            Ukraine     31
28 2017-05-30            Vietnam     18
29 2017-05-31          Argentina      3
30 2017-05-31              China  14477
31 2017-05-31            Czechia     35
32 2017-05-31              India      6
33 2017-05-31            Liberia      1
34 2017-05-31    No Identificado      1
35 2017-05-31  Republic of Korea      1
36 2017-05-31             Russia      1
37 2017-05-31      United States      3
```

Si hago un SORT inverso en la fuente de datos, el archivo cambia iniciando en 31, 30, 2 y 1

De las dos maneras, al plotear se grafica en el orden que está el arreglo (columna) y no en el orden del calendario (30,31,1,2), resultando esto (ya sea 31,30,2,1 o 1,2,30,31).

[image: Fig.3]

**Cómo puedo ordenar la columna de fecha en el orden del calendario?**

Mi código:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from  matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator, AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter

df = pd.read_csv("72hcountcountry.csv", delimiter=',', parse_dates = ['Fecha','count'], dayfirst=True)
grupos = df.groupby(['Pais'])

print df

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

color=iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(grupos))))

for nombre, grupo in grupos:
    ax.plot_date(x = grupo['Fecha'], y = grupo['count'], color = next(color), marker='o', ls = 'solid', label=nombre)


locator = DayLocator()
formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.autoscale_view()

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.margins(0.05)

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que los datos de la columna "Fecha" son tipo objeto

Si los cambias a tipo datatime deberías de poder ordenarlos por fecha

```
df["Fecha"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Fecha"])
```

Si compruebas el los tipos del dataframe verás que ahora si esta como datatime:

```
>>> test.dtypes

Fecha         datetime64[ns]
Pais                  object
count                  int64
dtype: object
```

He usado solo un par de filas y modificado las fechas pero a mi me va ok ahora:

```
>>> df.head()
Unnamed: 0      Fecha       Pais  count
0           0 2017-01-06  Argentina      1
1           1 2017-04-06      China  31230
2           2 2017-02-06    Ecuador      1
3           3 2017-01-06      Egypt      2
4           4 2017-01-06     Latvia    360

>>> test.sort_values(["Fecha"])
Unnamed: 0      Fecha       Pais  count
0           0 2017-01-06  Argentina      1
3           3 2017-01-06      Egypt      2
4           4 2017-01-06     Latvia    360
2           2 2017-02-06    Ecuador      1
1           1 2017-04-06      China  31230
```

[m3_stackoverflow UPDATE]

No se altera el orden del arreglo/columna, se mantiene el orden y al invocar la grafica lo hace con el orden del arreglo, no del SORT.

usé `df = df.sort_values(["Fecha"])`

```
        Fecha               Pais  count
0  2017-05-31          Argentina      3
1  2017-05-31              China  14477
2  2017-05-31            Czechia     35
3  2017-05-31              India      6
4  2017-05-31            Liberia      1
5  2017-05-31    No Identificado      1
6  2017-05-31  Republic of Korea      1
7  2017-05-31             Russia      1
8  2017-05-31      United States      3
9  2017-05-30          Argentina      1
10 2017-05-30              China   4022
11 2017-05-30            Ecuador      1
12 2017-05-30             France     16
13 2017-05-30            Germany      2
14 2017-05-30          Indonesia      1
15 2017-05-30    No Identificado     56
16 2017-05-30            Romania      1
17 2017-05-30             Russia      4
18 2017-05-30             Sweden    158
19 2017-05-30             Taiwan      1
20 2017-05-30            Ukraine     31
21 2017-05-30            Vietnam     18
22 2017-06-02          Argentina      2
23 2017-06-02             Canada      1
24 2017-06-02              China   3980
25 2017-06-02    Slovak Republic      3
26 2017-06-02             Sweden      1
27 2017-06-02            Ukraine     99
28 2017-06-01          Argentina      1
29 2017-06-01              China  31230
30 2017-06-01            Ecuador      1
31 2017-06-01              Egypt      2
32 2017-06-01             Latvia    360
33 2017-06-01           Portugal      1
34 2017-06-01    Slovak Republic      2
35 2017-06-01             Taiwan      2
36 2017-06-01            Ukraine     31
37 2017-06-01     United Kingdom      1
        Fecha               Pais  count
18 2017-05-30             Sweden    158
21 2017-05-30            Vietnam     18
20 2017-05-30            Ukraine     31
19 2017-05-30             Taiwan      1
17 2017-05-30             Russia      4
16 2017-05-30            Romania      1
15 2017-05-30    No Identificado     56
14 2017-05-30          Indonesia      1
13 2017-05-30            Germany      2
9  2017-05-30          Argentina      1
10 2017-05-30              China   4022
11 2017-05-30            Ecuador      1
12 2017-05-30             France     16
0  2017-05-31          Argentina      3
7  2017-05-31             Russia      1
6  2017-05-31  Republic of Korea      1
5  2017-05-31    No Identificado      1
4  2017-05-31            Liberia      1
3  2017-05-31              India      6
2  2017-05-31            Czechia     35
1  2017-05-31              China  14477
8  2017-05-31      United States      3
35 2017-06-01             Taiwan      2
34 2017-06-01    Slovak Republic      2
33 2017-06-01           Portugal      1
32 2017-06-01             Latvia    360
31 2017-06-01              Egypt      2
30 2017-06-01            Ecuador      1
29 2017-06-01              China  31230
37 2017-06-01     United Kingdom      1
36 2017-06-01            Ukraine     31
28 2017-06-01          Argentina      1
27 2017-06-02            Ukraine     99
26 2017-06-02             Sweden      1
24 2017-06-02              China   3980
23 2017-06-02             Canada      1
22 2017-06-02          Argentina      2
25 2017-06-02    Slovak Republic      3
```

Aún así se mantiene igual el plot

Si tengo como DATE el tipo de la columna en el array

```
>>> df.dtypes
Fecha    datetime64[ns]
Pais             object
count            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: No funciona así, solo hace el SORT, pero al volver a invocar la gráfica, sigue tomando el orden del arreglo (el orden que muestra en la primera columna:Unnamed, no se altera con el SORT_VALUES)

Comment: Será que asigno a un df2 el sort?

Comment: Funcionó, usando `df2 = df.sort_values(["Fecha"])` y luego graficando df2